# Data recovery from a SSD drive

Tags: ssd

I'm nowhere near an hacker or security guy. I'm just a dad of two young kids who loves to travel. I don't know if it's ok to ask here, but what you guys talk about is way over my head but I thought you might have an idea.

A few months ago, my 2010 macbook air was really slow so I decided to make a safety copy of my system using Time Machine and a Time Capsule and I formatted my mac SSD drive to do a fresh (re)install of Mac OS X. I didn't use my backup from Time Machine to start again because I wanted everything to be fresh and new. But what I didn't know at that time is Time Machine would continue to create a backup of my system with the same name. So all my kids/travel photos, videos, documents of my previous system were gone. I kept on using my macbook air for a few months before I realized everything was gone on my time capsule. Now, I have a new macbook pro so I took my old SSD drive from my old macbook air off and I bought an Envoy case so I could use it as an external drive to try to recover my files. I have no idea if there was a fire vault actived on this drive neither do I know about TRIM. All I know is I can browse my old system files using this setup. When I use any of the data recovery software I can find on the internet, all I find are the files that were "created" after I formatted and (re)started my system but nothing prior to that.

Is there a way a non-phd or masterrussianhacker could recover those files?

Thank you very much!

Jonathan

Comment: If the drive does support TRIM (a SSD feature to queue blocks of data for being truly erased), then most likely the formatting or another activity activated TRIM across the entire drive. Assuming the SSD firmware is not particularly buggy, this guarantees all data has been lost.

Comment: "*I can browse my old system files using this setup*" - so you've got a working solution?

Comment: Are you sure you are using Time Capsule the right way? Sure it continues to make backups, but you should be able to go back in time and view older backups.

Comment: Agreed. Open Time Machine, and you'll see a list of backup dates. Scroll back to "a few months ago" and restore.

Answer (score 10):

Your best chance for recovery is through a professional disk recovery service.  If the data can be retrieved, they are the ones to do it.  Of course, these services are very expensive (don't be surprised by a four figure quote because the task is labor intensive,) but if the files are worth it to you, and you have the resources, consider it.

If you want to play around yourself, the first thing to do is purchase a *hardware* USB Write Blocker, [perhaps something like this one if it works with your SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005C55OYA), to make sure you don't accidentally or intentionally overwrite any of the data on your SSD as you start your explorations.

Next, check out [The Sleuth Kit (TSK)](http://www.sleuthkit.org/) and [Autopsy](http://www.sleuthkit.org/autopsy/).  The Sleuth Kit is a free forensic analysis toolkit that includes disk analysis tools, including the ability to recover deleted files.  Autopsy is a graphical front end to TSK and other tools, and includes modules to perform tasks like viewing images.

The trick to using Autopsy is to understand the language of its steps.  Always keep in mind the tool is intended for use by law enforcement investigators, who are looking for evidence of criminal activity, such as child porn, drugs, lists of contacts, old emails, recently edited files, hacking tools, etc., and they speak their own language.  None of that will apply to you, of course, but it helps to view the steps through their eyes.

Read the documentation, but the first thing you'll need is to create a case.  That's just a file to track all the stuff you do.  The case will then need a "data source" - all you do is pick "local drive", then your write-blocked SSD.

You then tell Autopsy to "ingest" the data source, which is where it runs a bunch of tools on the disk to figure out what's on it.  Most of the law enforcement stuff won't apply to you, so when you ingest the data source, turn off the ingest modules for things that obviously won't apply, things like "hashes", "virtual machines", "email parsers", etc.

Autopsy will then start processing the disk.  It runs in the background and can take a very long time; the larger the disk, the longer it takes.  You can look at files as soon as it starts showing them to you, but once you confirm it's working, you may as well step back and let it finish.

You'll probably be most interested in using the manual tool called the Image Gallery Module.  This is a fast viewer that will let you zip through all the images it finds.  As you find files you want to save, you can right click on them and export them as local files.

Keep in mind that the tool is intended to find files that have been hidden or deleted.  If you may have images on the drive (perhaps in your browser history) you wouldn't be willing to share with other members of your family, perform the drive recovery in private!

Good luck!

Comment: Hardware write blockers are useful to prevent the operating system from inadvertently messing with the data, but it will not prevent a SSD which has marked certain blocks for erasure with TRIM from finishing its task when it is next powered up. There is a small chance that the data is marked for TRIM but the garbage collector has not gotten around to actually doing it yet. Powering up the drive, even with a write blocker, is the worst thing you could do.

Comment: OP states that he has been _actively using the disk for several months_ before deciding to try to recover something. I believe the chances that even professional services can recover anything at this point are nonexistent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll give it a try:)

Answer (score 1):

Although I MUST second Johns answer to defer such delicate work to proper data recovery specialists, please ALSO **talk to Apple**! Maybe they can dig deep(er) into your backup and retrieve your originally backed-up files for you. If they can, that would certainly be both faster and cheaper than the data recovery route, and also the restored files would be accurately reproduced (with data recovery, you might be missing bits of data here and there, which might translate into anything from ugly blocks in some photos to downright unreadable files).

I don't know how Time Capsule works (not a Mac user myself), but usually with backups you should be able to retrieve older revisions of files -- or deleted files. The time span might mean that they have flushed some data, I don't know.

You might also look into adjusting your backup settings (insofar as you can) so that it "never" deletes files from your backup if they are deleted from your local system (after all, that's the point of a backup, no?).

Comment: Apple do not do data recovery. There's no reason that they would have access to any better tools than anyone else. Time Machine *does* keep older versions of files, and the interface allows these to be recovered very easily. If the question asker is saying the files are gone, this is because the data has been overwritten by newer backups.

Comment: I was not intending to imply that Apple offers recovery services (of customer storage), only that they might have better access _to the backups they store_. Apparently not...

Comment: Yes the old backups seem to be gone since I made the mistake to give my new system the same name so when Time Machine created a new backup on the Time Capsule, it overwrote the existing backups :(

Comment: :( You have my sincere sympathy, as well as wishes for the best of luck. That really seems to be an unfortunate "feature" of Time Capsule.

Answer (score 0):

What usually happens is that Time Machine starts a new backup, and your other backup is just sitting there unused because Time Machine doesn't think that re-installed computer is the same one as the "other" computer it has a backup for.

You may be able to see the other backup easily, by holding option while clicking on the Time Machine icon in your menu bar. Select "Browse other backup disks". It might offer no disks, in which case you need to access the Time Capsule's drive first.

If you don't have a menu bar icon for Time Machine, you can enable it via the Time Machine panel of System Preferences.

Bear in mind that operations on a Time Capsule can be extremely slow. You might want to enable Finder's status bar (via the View menu) so that you can see the spinner in the bottom right.

To access the Time Capsule drive itself, check the sidebar of Finder. It should show up as the name of the Time Capsule itself under Shared, which will usually lead to a volume named "Data". It doesn't always select it when you double-click, so look through the sidebar if you don't see any action after a few minutes.

Once you have it open, you will see the sparsebundles of the various backups. Every computer that backs up to the Time Capsule will have its own file, as may computers that have started a new backup set after an erase. I don't recommend opening a Time Capsule backup file via Finder, because it's slow and copying files directly can cause issues for future backups.

Whether you do or don't find another backup set, another issue that can occur is that your current home folder may not have been made with the same specific details as it was in the first time, and so Time Machine may not realize it should show it to you. Enter Time Machine via the Time Machine menu bar icon, navigate to the Macintosh HD and then into the Users folder. Then have a look at the timeline on the right side, hovering over a line will show you the date of that backup. If you find a backup from the right era, you may then be able to restore the items.

I know this is a lot of information to process, but feel free to ask any questions that arise.

Comment: This way, I can go back in time until September 2015 even if I've been using this time capsule since 2010... September 2015 is the moment I decided to restart everything.